# Decorating a nullable field as a non-nullable property for code first Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I'm adding Linq to SQL attributes to a pre-existing class (where it would be a breaking change to change the data type of the properties) I did think that specifying the Storage parameter of the `ColumnAttribute` would instruct the Linq to SQL bits to interact directly with the backing field, so I would *expect* something like below to work:

```
Private _foo As Integer? = 0
<Column(CanBeNull:=True, DbType:="INT", Name:="FooBar", Storage:="_foo")> _
<DefaultValue(0)> _
Public Property Foo() As Integer
    Get
        Return If(_foo.HasValue, _foo.Value, 0)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
        _foo = If(Value = 0, New Integer?(), Value)
    End Set
End Property
```

After giving it a whirl, with a basic:

```
MyThing target = (from u in context.MyThings select u).First();
```

I'm finding that this fails with:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type..

So, is it possible to markup the existing code to work with Linq to SQL without making a breaking change, or do I have to add a duplicate property for the LINQ to SQL version?

Comment: The error seems pretty descriptive: you are using a nullable integer (`_foo`) when a non-nullable integer is expected. Just account for the right type (i.e., `Integer` instead of `Integer?`).

Comment: @varocarbas The error is the other way around - the column on the database is nullable; my backing field is nullable, just my property that isn't (which is happily mapping the nullable backing field to the non-nullable type)

Comment: Well... it is not too clear what is what from your question. But the whole point of my suggestion holds anyway: just rely on the right type. Everything nullable or everything non-nullable. If you want more to the point advices you should post an easily-reproduceable sample helping everyone to understand the problem properly.

Comment: @varocarbas Changing the type of the property would be a breaking change on this type (which happens to be used in about 8 products)

Comment: This starts to be like an endless loop. The basic solution is clear: use the same types. If this is not acceptable because of your exact requirements; explain these requirements properly (, allow us to test your conditions) and ask for alternatives. I mean... you are not precisely new in SO and you should know how this works: help us to help you :)

Comment: @varocarbas I thought I'd been clear in my question, referencing the attempt to use the Storage property of the ColumnAttribute, as well as the requirement of not making a breaking change

Comment: OK. Then my bad. Good luck with the search of help.

Answer (score -2):

Try....

```
If(IsNothing(_foo), 0, _foo.Value)
```

Comment: You could also set a default value of 0 in DB for that field. Then do a global update and change all Null to 0.

Comment: This is a runtime error when loading from the DB via Linq to SQL, not a compile time issue